# Jekyll Requiring "excerpt" Liquid Tag in YAML Front Matter

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll, liquid

I've got a blog built on Jekyll 3.0.1 [based on this Kasper theme](http://jekyllthemes.org/themes/kasper/) with some modification. I've removed all the posts but one in an effort to reduce the degrees of freedom in the problem I'm having.  The site builds fine when I include an "excerpt" tag and a value for it inside the post's YAML front matter, but when I remove this I get an error (shown below).  I've tried using an "excerpt_separator" tag and value in the _config.yml file and putting the separator in the post, but this doesn't help.  Just for the hell of it I even put in a default "excerpt" tag and value inside the _config.yml and this didn't help either.  It seems to me like my Jekyll installation is no longer auto-generating excerpts properly since it does build when I manually include an "excerpt" in the post's YAML front matter.

Here is the Github repository:
https://github.com/jtelszasz/kasper-trial

```
users-MacBook-Air:kasper-trial user$ jekyll serve --trace
Configuration file: /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_config.yml
Source: /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial
Destination: /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_site
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
Generating... 
Deprecation: Collection#map should be called on the #docs array directly.
Called by /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:46:in `block in generate'.
Deprecation: Collection#count should be called on the #docs array directly.
Called by /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:49:in `rescue in block in generate'.
Deprecation: Collection#reverse should be called on the #docs array directly.
Called by /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:51:in `block in generate'.
Deprecation: Document#title is now a key in the #data hash.
Called by /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in generate'.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/document.rb:471:in `method_missing': undefined method `excerpt' for #<Jekyll::Document _posts/2015-11-30-blah.md collection=posts> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:55:in `block (3 levels) in generate'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rss/maker/base.rb:57:in `new_item'
from /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in generate'
from /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:51:in `each'
from /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:51:in `block in generate'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rss/maker/base.rb:438:in `make'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rss/maker/base.rb:402:in `make'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rss/maker.rb:28:in `make'
from /Users/user/Documents/kasper-trial/_plugins/rssgenerator.rb:41:in `generate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:154:in `block in generate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:153:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:153:in `generate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/site.rb:58:in `process'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:60:in `build'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:35:in `process'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/bin/jekyll:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you have github repository ?

Comment: Just added to the post.  Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in `_plugins/rssgenerator.rb` line 55.

```
item.description = parser.convert(post.excerpt)
```

should be :

```
item.description = parser.convert(post.to_liquid['excerpt'])
```

Remove it and use standard jekyll file to generate your feed ([find it here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/jekyll/master/lib/site_template/feed.xml)).

In _config.yml add :

```
excerpt_separator: "<!--excerpt-->"
```

Your post :

```
---
layout: post
title: Post Title
description: "blah."
modified: 2014-12-17
category: articles
tags: [futbol]
---
excerpt

<!--excerpt-->

asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Just out of curiosity, what was the specific problem in that rssgenerator.rb file?